Are there exploration incentives to take one of each class in your party?
In the Dragon Age series, there are three base classes (warrior, rogue, and mage). In Dragon Age: The Veilguard, your party size is also three, down from the traditional party size of four used in previous games in the series. This means it is impossible to take along a companion the same class as your own player character without losing out on one of the other classes to make room.
Are there exploration or environmental details in The Veilguard that would strongly encourage ensuring your party always has one of each class? For example, in Dragon Age: Inquisition, exploration occasionally presented tasks that only a specific class could perform -- locks that only rogues could pick, walls that only warriors could bash down, and rubble that only mages could 'energize' into place or out of the way. Are these kinds of barriers present again? Or can we build parties more flexibly with the companions we wish, without having to worry about getting blocked somewhere and having to swap people out?
(This question is not about combat incentives to take one of each class, e.g. combos and synergies.)

I am aware the game is not out yet. However, there was recently a hands-on preview event with a fair amount of coverage, and one of the attendees may have already said the answer. If not, this question should be trivial to answer in a month.
